# Choice of test statistics in one-sided and two-sided tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, mathematical-statistics

This question could be trivial, since it goes through the basics, but I cannot find clear explanations or at least explanations that I understand.

Suppose we have a normal distribution $X \sim N(\mu,1)$ and we do hypothesis testing with a single observation.

Than in the case of a two-sided test:

$H_0: \mu=0$, $H_1:\mu \ne 0$

we would reject at a certain $\alpha$ level if $P(|X|>c_{\alpha})=\alpha$

Instead for a one-sided test:

$H_0: \mu \le 0$, $H_1:\mu \ge 0$

we would reject at a certain $\alpha$ level if $P(X>d_{\alpha})=\alpha$

These are the tests routinely implemented, as far as I could understand.

My question is how we choose the test statistics $|X|$ and $X$ in the two cases. I have seen some derivations (e.g. in Casella&Berger), that derived these tests from the likelyhood ratio test and the c.d.f. of the resulting statistics, but to me they do not seem really derived from a "principle" of optimality and there are choices involved. Note that we are not in the case of simple hypothesis where we have the Neyman-Pearson lemma at rescue.

My question is: "how we can "derive" these rejection regions from a principle of optimality" ( e.g. maximizing the power of the test in some sense... ) and without too many ad-hoc/sensible/intuitive choices ?

Comment: Search for "uniformly most powerful" (UMP) tests.  Wikipedia [has a short description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_most_powerful_test#The_Karlin%E2%80%93Rubin_theorem).  These are described in standard textbooks such as Lehmann, Kendall & Stuart, *etc.*

Comment: Thanks I was really struggling in finding a proof.

Comment: Among these books, which one would you suggest to buy ? They are both quite old...